# Passing a variable to a query in google-drive-api files().list function

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a function which takes in a directory name as a parameter and returns the ID of the directory. The ultimate goal is to list the files in said directory using the returned file ID, however I can't seem to figure out the syntax for passing the directory name in as a variable.

I can only manage to do something of the following, where I need to explicitly type in the name of the directory. Please note that I am using v3 of the google drive api.

```
def get_folder_id():

    folder_ID = ""

    while True:
        response = drive_service.files().list(
            q="name='folder1'", fields="nextPageToken, files(id,name)").execute()

        files = response.get('files', [])

        for item in files:
            print ("Found file: %s, %s" % (item['name'], item['id']))
            folder_ID = item['id']

        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)

        if page_token == None:
            break

    return folder_ID
```

How can I pass the folder name as a parameter and still include it in the q query?

I've tried variants such as:

```
response = drive_service.files().list(
            q='"name="' + "'" + f_name + "'" + '"', fields="nextPageToken, files(id,name)").execute()
```

In an attempt to include the single quotes around the request, but this doesn't work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the folder ID from the folder name using Drive API v3 with Python.

If my understanding is correct, how about using the following search query? Please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
q='"name="' + "'" + f_name + "'" + '"'
```

#### To:

```
q="name='" + f_name + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"
```

- In this modification, the search query was modified.

  - `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` means the folder.
  - `trashed=false` means files outside of the trash box.

By above search query, the folders which has the folder name of `f_name` are retrieved.

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: That wasn't exactly the question, however you answered the question within, thank you. The issue I was facing was I couldn't get the right combination of quotes in order to pass the name in as a variable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already got the answer for your question.
However, if you want to pass the variable name as part of the query in GoogleDrive request then append the variable name with + before and after it.
year_id = "Blah Blah'
Example :- q="parents in '"+year_id+"'

Happy coding!!!

Comment: wrap your code in ``` ``` to make your code easier to read. And I think you have written an error in as well with the quotation marks